# Include function alias

Tags: doxygen

I have a library, `Foo/Foo.h`

```cpp
/**
My core library.
*/
namespace Foo {

/**
My function.
*/
void myfunc();

} // namespace Foo
```

And a library that uses that library, `Bar/Bar.h`

```cpp
#include <Foo.h>

/**
Library using alias.
*/
namespace Bar {

/**
\copydoc Foo::myfunc()
*/
using Foo::myfunc;

} // namespace Bar
```

Now my question is simple: How do I include the documentation of `Foo::myfunc` in the `Bar` namespace?

In particular, with the `Doxyfile`:

```
INPUT = Foo Bar
```

doxygen 1.9.1 *does not* show the included function:

[image]

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Did you have a look at `\copydoc` and friends.

Comment: @albert Thanks for the suggestion! That seems indeed what I need. However, I did `/** \copydoc Foo::myfunc() */ using Foo::myfunc;` which shows nothing in the docs, neither does it give a warning. Note that I am on 1.9.1.

Comment: I see the documentation, please extend your example with what you added (so a full example. Note the Doxyfile information is best displayed from running `doxygen -x`)

Comment: The `using` is not a documentable entity, so you have to use something else (e.g. add it to the namespace description).

Comment: @albert I edited the question for completeness, though your last comment basically answers the question: it cannot be done.

Comment: Maybe an idea is to create an enhancement issue in the doxygen issue tracker, though I'm not 100% sure whether it is conceptually possible.

Comment: I also assume that you have `RECURSIVE=YES` set otherwise `INPUT = Foo Bar` won't do anything.

Comment: I used the default, which is `NO` according to the docs. However, settings it to `YES` does not change anything